# UK work visa with pending criminal charge

Tags: uk, germany, working-visas, criminal-records

I have a tier-2 work visa application in progress. I had submitted the application on 24th December and my appointment is on 3rd of January. I am an Indian citizen currently residing and working in Berlin, Germany.
I was traveling in train on 25th Dec and unfortunately forgot to purchase a valid ticket. The controller handed me over to the police who made a report/charge, for criminal offence, and gave me a fine for 60 euro. I paid the fine immediately and asked the police what will happen with the charge. They said in most cases it is scrapped and I will get the outcome by notice in about a month. I have already selected, no, as an answer for any criminal conviction/charge, in my visa application. What should I do about it ? The police said because it’s a very small offence it should not affect my visa application but I’d appreciate more input on this matter.

------EDIT-------
The document I received, states that:

In German:

> Beschuldigtenvernehmung im Strafverfahren

"Erklärung. Mit wurde eröffnet, welche Tat/Taten mir zur Last gelegt wird/werden (§163a Abs.4 StPO).(siehe Seite 2)". In a separate document the charge is "Erschleichen von Leistungen"
Ends with, "Ich gebe die Tat zu. Ich gene die Tat nicht zu" (I have selected neither)

In English:

> Police questioning in criminal proceedings.

Declaration: I have been informed of the offence with which I am charged. (the offence is fraudulent acquisition of payments, in a
   separate document)
Then there is information about my rights for getting a lawyer.
The document ends with wether I admit the charge or not, I have not selected anything.

Comment: In my opinion this is trivial.

Comment: I agree the charge is not serious. But do I need to make a new application, so that I can mention it ? @HonoraryWorldCitizen

Comment: In my opinion NO. Read the answer and all the comments on this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/127094/arrested-after-uk-visa-application

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen thank-you for that link. If I go ahead with my current application, would you suggest I mention this charge during the interview, citing the fact that it happened after I had submitted the application.

Comment: That will be fine, and have all the documents from the court or police etc. Are personal interviews conducted for the UK visa?

Comment: I am not sure, but I have to go to the visa application centre to show various documents and get my biometrics taken. I am assuming that it's an interview.

Comment: It’s not an interview. UK stopped interviews long ago. I don’t see why you’re still fixated on reporting this minor infraction, but sure go ahead.

Comment: Then do I just keep this information to myself ?

Comment: You have to make that decision yourself after all we have told you.

Answer (score 5):

As far as German law is concerned, you have not been **charged** or **convicted** of a crime or misdemeanor yet. Those 60 euros you paid are not a *fine*, they are an *increased fare*.

The police will investigate (i.e. write up what you and the conductor said) and pass the information to the prosecution, which has the options of charging you ([Anklage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anklage)), offering a plea bargain ([Strafbefehl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafbefehlsverfahren_(Deutschland))), or closing the case ([Einstellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellung_des_Strafverfahrens_(Deutschland))).

It would be remarkably fast if anything happens before your visa interview, so at that point you will be neither charged nor convicted. You will be under a police investigation that may or may not result in a charge.

Comment: Please check my edit. I have added information regarding the report given to me.

Comment: @AyushVerma, is "charged" your translation or an official one?

Comment: The german version of the document states "Mit wurde eröffnet, welche Tat/Taten mir zur Last gelegt wird/werden (§ 163a Abs.4 StPO ). (siehe Seite 2)"
The english version of the document is as I have mentioned.

Comment: @AyushVerma, the German version uses words which do not imply a charge in court *yet*.

Comment: Hmm, that't what I thought. The police officer had also mentioned that this is a report. He said, in a bit broken english, "once you have paid the fine/increased fare" this report ends in the bin. Ok Thank-you very much for your answer !

Comment: The UK form also asks about caution, fine, discharge, or community sentence. So it may be a yes to that but no to a conviction or charge. Re the bin, that is common for first offenses of this kind; it is not literally a trashcan and they count previous closures for repeat offenders. At some point they don't close the case any more.

Comment: @o.m nope, it's not a yes to any of the above. In UK law a caution is an admission of guilt and is an alternative to prosecution. A fine, discharge or community sentence will be imposed by a criminal court if it finds the alleged offender guilty.